# Angular Material attribute binding for button classes

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular15, angular-material-15

I want to render a raised or a strike button in Angular Material - depending on a variable from backend's code behind.

I tried this:

```
<button
   [attr.mat-raised-button]="this.myValue === false ? '' : null"
   [attr.mat-stroked-button]="this.myValue === true ? '' : null"
   color="primary">
   ButtonTitle
</button>
```

And magically the correct attribute is set - if I inspect the rendered code. But it isn't "used" or "applied" in someway. Thus, the button looks like it has no attribute set:

[image]

But depending on `this.myValue` the button should look like a one of these buttons:

[image]

Demo:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-zsnfkb-xcdfqh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it short, you can't with ease.

But you can still play with `*ngIf` to display the desired button.

```html
<button mat-stroked-button
   color="primary" *ngIf="this.myValue === true">
   ButtonTitle
</button>
<button mat-raised-button
   color="primary" *ngIf="this.myValue === false">
   ButtonTitle
</button>
```

Even better, if you use it often, you can encapsulate the logic into a specific component.

Comment: Ok, I feared that - but the code for "title" and the other attributes for styling etc in the button are much more extensive than in this simplified example - and I hate code duplicating ;-)

Comment: There was this work done on the dynamic directive but it doesn't answer to our issue, sorry https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/8785

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is a valid approach (using `[attr.mat-raised-button]` ), but using ngIf would surely be a good approach.

Similar to this:

```
    <div *ngIf="myValue">
      <button mat-raised-button color="primary">
        ButtonTitle
      </button>
    </div>
```

More details about ngIf [here](https://www.makeuseof.com/angular-built-in-directives-ngif-ngfor-ngclass/).